# how to Read the File untill last line and wait for data to be availbale in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have requirement where I need parse all the lines of the text file until the last line, and to wait for the Data to be available in a text file **(contents of the file are filepaths in each line)** 
I have written the node js code as follows utilizing the **readStream,Readable.resume(),Readable.pause()**

---

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = "C:\\Temp\\removeme.txt";

var watching = false;

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

readStream.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    if(watching) readStream.pause();
});

watching = true;

fs.watch(filename,{persistent: true}, (event,file_name) => {
    if(event === 'change') {
        readStream.resume();
    }
});
```

However, once the watch is started, I can get the events whenever I update the file using **echo "Test String" >> C:\Temp\removeme.txt** but not the data event on readStream. I tried diffirent ways without any success. Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As *they* say: "There's a module for that!"

See [`file-tail`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-tail)

In future, I find npm to be an invaluable resource for finding modules! Select two or three words that best describe what you're looking for and use them in the `npm search` command, as in:

`$> npm search file tail`

which produces:

`NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS

read-chunk                | Read a chunk from a… | =sindresorhus   | 2017-07-30 | 2.1.0    | read file readfile fs chunk slice part head tail buffer fd open
tail                      | tail a file in node  | =lucagrulla     | 2017-10-22 | 1.2.3    | tail file
fs-tail-stream            | fs.createReadStream… | =eugeneware     | 2017-02-02 | 1.1.0    | fs createReadStream tail tailing watch watching
...
...`

Or submit your words to the search bar at [`npmjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/).